# Laravel 4 Unable to Output Data for Complex Model Structure

Tags: php, sql, laravel-4, eloquent

First post so here goes:

I'm building a stats website with Laravel 4 and have set up relationships between several models - 
Player, Game, Team, PlayerData, StatType

All of these have corresponding tables:
players: id, name, team_id

```
games: id, home_team_id, away_team_id, week (note 2 teams in a single game)
teams: id, name
stat_types: id, name
player_datas: id, player_id, stat_type_id, stat_value, game_id
```

The idea being that every player plays for a team, who plays once a week, and each stat for a player in each game will have an entry in the player datas table (e.g. player 1, stat_id 1, value 2, game 1, player 1, stat_id 2, value 10, game 1)

<strike>So what I'm looking to do is output a table when someone wants to view a player on the player show.blade.php (*** represents placeholder):</strike>

******UPDATE:** I've got the data i want to appear by making Watcher's suggested changes, but getting the 2nd and 3rd cells like below (in my view) seems inefficient? Think I'm missing something

```
@foreach($team_fixtures as $team_fixture)

<tr>
    <td>{{$team_fixture->homeTeam->team_name}} vs {{$team_fixture->awayTeam->team_name}}</td>
    <td>{{$team_fixture->playerData()->where('player_id', $player->id)
    ->where('stat_type_id', '1')
    ->pluck('stat_value')}}</td>
    <td>{{$team_fixture->playerData()->where('player_id', $player->id)
    ->where('stat_type_id', '2')
    ->pluck('stat_value')}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

<strike>I can't tell whether I'm missing a pivot table (player_data_stat_types??) or have got the relationships wrong? If there's a better way to structure I'd be happy to do that, I'm just not sure where to start with this one. I started doing a for each $team_fixtures but could not get the stats to output. My problem is that the fixture is the left hand column, but the player data table has multiple entries against a game_id...</strike>

My player controller looks like:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $player = Player::findOrFail($id);
    $team_fixtures = Game::where('home_team_id', '=', $player->team_id)
                    ->orWhere('away_team_id', '=', $player->team_id)
                    ->get();

    return View::make('site/players.show', compact('player', 'team_fixtures'));
}
```

And Models are linked as follows:
Team:

```
public function players() {
    return $this->hasMany('Player');
}

public function games() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Game');
}
```

Player:

```
public function team() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Team');
}

public function playerData(){
    return $this->hasMany('PlayerData');
}
```

Game:

```
public function playerData() {
    return $this->hasMany('PlayerData');
}

public function homeTeam()
{
return $this->hasOne('Team', 'id', 'home_team_id');
}

public function awayTeam()
{
return $this->hasOne('Team', 'id', 'away_team_id');
}

public function playerData(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Player', 'player_id', 'id');
}
```

PlayerData:

```
public function statType(){
    return $this->belongsTo('StatType', 'stat_id', 'id');
} 

public function game(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Game');
}
```

StatType:

```
public function playerData(){
    return $this->hasMany('PlayerData');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firs off, your relations are wrong. Here's how they should look like:

```
// Player
public function team()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Team');
}

public function stats()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('StatType', 'player_datas')
      ->withPivot('game_id', 'stat_value'); 
}


// Team
public function players()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Player');
}

public function awayGames()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Game', 'away_team_id');
}

public function homeGames()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Game', 'home_team_id');
}


// Game
public function homeTeam()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Team', 'home_team_id'); 
}

public function awayTeam()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Team', 'away_team_id');
}

public function players()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Player', 'player_datas')
       ->withPivot('stat_value', 'stat_type_id'); 
}
```

I don't think you need `PlayerData` model at all, and I assume your `stat_types` table has `name` instead of `value` field.

Then, to achieve what you wanted, ie. to show user's performance (stats values) for each game, you want something like this:

```
// controller
$player = Player::find($id);
$stats = $player->stats->groupBy('pivot.game_id');

// view
<ul>
    @foreach ($games as $game)
      <li>
        {{ $game->homeTeam->name }} vs {{ $game->awayTeam->name }}
        <table>
          @foreach ($stats->get($game->id) as $stat)
            <tr><td>{{ $stat->name }}: </td><td>{{ $stat->pivot->stat_value }}</td>
          @endforeach
        </table>
      </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: Cheers. I see what you're going for, but $games isn't defined. Should I just be passing in all games from the controller or what I was already doing? Because if I pass in $team_fixtures (see OP) and do foreach $team_fixtures as $game, it says that $game->stats->get($game->id) is an invalid foreach argument?

Comment: `$games` in my example is just the same as your `$team_fixtures`, I just used name of the model, so it's easier to read. Then, there is no `stats` on `$game`, `stats` is a relation on the `$player` - nested foreach.

Comment: ah right i think i see what you're saying - have a pivot table between games and players (i guess really i should follow Laravel naming conventions and get rid of 'player_datas'?) and use the many to many relationship to get to the stats related to a player

Comment: Exactly, your `player_datas` is pivot table linking player-game-stat. In this case probably best name would be something like `appearances` or something similar, not necessarily `game_player_stat` (Eloquent convention), but `player_datas` is a bad name for sure.

Comment: I still can't get this to work. The team names are fine, but i keep getting 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach'. $player->stats->get($game->id) doesn't produce all stats, it just seems to retrieve 1 row from the stat_types table (along with the relevant info from the pivot table) not an array -
{"id":2,"stat_type":"Assists","opta_id":"2","score_weighting":"5","pivot":{"player_id":1,"stat_type_id":2,"game_id":2,"stat_value":2}}

so it is getting the stat value where the stat_type_id = the game id rather than doing getting all the stats for the game?

Comment: Are you sure you got this piece there: `$stats = $player->stats->groupBy('pivot.game_id');` ? And you're right, I made a little mistake, in the foreach there should be `$stats->get..` not `$player->stats..`! Edited.

Answer (score 0):

When you are declaring a relationship in a model, you should specify what you are relating the model *to*.  In your code I see at least one example of this:

```
// Game model
public function teams() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Game');
}
```

This should really be relating your Game model to your Team model, but you are relating games to games here.  Try this out:

```
public function teams() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Team');
}
```

The method names in the relationship simply set up an attribute with which you can use on an instance of your model, it has no other special meaning.  This will also work:

```
public function chicken() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Team');
}
```

With this, I could access the relationship of an instance by using `$game->chicken` and be able to iterate over many `Team` instances.

Another issue is that Eloquent relies on convention when using the other default parameters when declaring relationships.  If I have two models I want to relate, say `Modela` and `Modelb`, then it assumes the table names will be `modela` and `modelb`.  Furthermore, the linking column will be assumed to be `modelb_id`, for instance, inside the `modela` table.

You can override this behavior (which you will need to do at least for your `Game` relationships, since you have `home_team_id` and `away_team_id`). I refer you to the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships), but here's an example:

```
// Game model
public function homeTeam()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Team', 'home_team_id');
}
```

Notice I also changed your `belongsToMany` to a `hasOne`, which I think will work better for you and is more in line with what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i actually had my Game and Team Models (still wrongly) set up to relate to each other rather than themselves, i just suck at copying and pasting whilst at the office.

I get what you're saying so I'll update the models as per your suggestion and try to achieve what I'm aiming for though I'm still 100% sure what my foreach should look like to get the table to look like i want?